# Conflict between babel package and tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox, babel, incompatibility, pgfkeys

This code:

```
\documentclass[a4papaer, 12pt, landscape]{article}

%%% Format margines ...
\usepackage[margin = 15mm]{geometry}

%%%   Get more control over colors
\usepackage[tabel]{xcolor}

%%% Add boxes to write in ...
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%%%   Add support for langauges other than English.
\usepackage[turkish, english,bidi=default]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Script=Arabic,Scale = 1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[width = 5cm]
        hi
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

works fine as long as I comment out the babel package usage, but when using babel, it gives this error:
"! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/width = 5cm' and I am going to ignore it."

The same error is raised with any option that is used with tcolorbox.
It is obvious that this is a conflict between babel and tcolorbox, and I need both, but I was not able to find a solution for this conflict.
Hope I can find a solution with you.
Thanks

Comment: Can't test it right now, but I'm using `tcolorbox` with `babel` in many of my documents without problems. Did you try it without optional arguments? Since the error mentions `pgf` also try to comment package `pgf` out. But at the moment I can only guess.

Comment: @lukeflo, Thanks, Actually I added the usage of  'pfg' package as a try to solve the problem, it did not work, and I forgot to remove it. I edited the code here to remove it.
As for the options, I mentioned that the error only occurs when I use options, which, again, I need to use.
The good news coming from you is that you have already used these two packages together with no problem.

Comment: the turkish language make the `= `  active and that breaks the keyval handling. you can deactivate shorthands e.g. with `\usepackage[turkish, english,shorthands=off]{babel}` see the babel documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thank you UlrikeFischer, this solved the problem. And you are absolutely right, I need to read babel documentation because I do not even know what "make the =  active"  means  :) .
And another question I want to ask is, how do you make this gray background for some parts of the text in your comment?

Comment: Look here: [Formatting help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Its Markdown syntax.

Comment: @lukeflo, Thanks

Comment: Since this answer might be interesting for other users, do anyone wants to provide a short answer which can be accepted (@UlrikeFischer, @OP)?